# onSaveInstanceState is not called on orientation change before onDestroy() to save data during orientation change

Tags: android

I am working on an android app where i have different layouts for landscape and portrait I want to save some data while the orientation changes and but I find that the onSaveInstanceState is not called when the orientation is changed, I have also debugged the onDestroy() method and it is calling it but is not calling onSaveInstanceState, what is the issue is there any other way to pass during orientation change or I am doing some thing wrong?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    outState.putInt("intTag", intValue);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

this is not calling at all I have debugged it as well

Comment: did you set `android:configChanges="orientation"` for the activity in androidmanifest.xml? It suppresses what you want to do in `onSaveInstanceState` on orientation changing.

Comment: yes i have settle this as well but surprisingly it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're overriding the wrong method. You need to override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`.

The method you're overriding only gets called if with the attribute `persistableMode` is set to `persistAcrossReboots` in your Manifest.

Comment: @ZubairAkber: If this answer has solved your problem please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: @ZubairAkber You have upvoted it but you haven't marked it as an accepted solution. Please use the checkmark underneath the downvote button to mark it as the accepted solution. If you'd like to read more about accepting an answer, [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks, saved lot of my time. Was not even able to find the issue with debugger.